# Multiple insert based on value of a field?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have a table t1:

```
ID    Period
---  --------
1       5
2       3
3       2
```

(The table in fact has 366 different IDs and their period can be 23, 24, or 25.)

I want to insert multiple rows in a table t2 with fields ID and Hour, where Hour(ID) in 1 ..Period(ID):

```
ID    Hour
---  -----
1     1
1     2
1     3
1     4
1     5
2     1
2     2
2     3
3     1
3     2
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `model` clause, for example:

```
with t1(ID, Period) as(
  select 1, 5 from dual union all
  select 2, 3 from dual union all
  select 3, 2 from dual
)
select ID
     , period as hour
  from t1
  model
  partition by (ID)
  dimension by (1 as indx)
  measures(period)
  rules(
     period[for indx from 1 to period[1] increment 1] = cv(indx)
  )
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52adb/7)

Result:

```
        ID      HOUR
---------- ----------
         1          1 
         1          2 
         1          3 
         1          4 
         1          5 
         2          1 
         2          2 
         2          3 
         3          1 
         3          2 

 10 rows selected
```

And your `insert` statement could look like this:

```
insert into t2(id, hour)
   select ID
        , period
     from t1
     model
     partition by (ID)
     dimension by (1 as indx)
     measures(period)
     rules(
        period[for indx from 1 to period[1] increment 1] = cv(indx)
     )
```

Comment: The thing is that the example here is smaller than the real table in which I have 366 IDs. I hope there exists a way that does not need a "select" per ID.

Comment: @user1777530 `exists a way that does not need a "select" per ID`. I'm not sure I'm following. Could you elaborate on this? It does not matter how big your table is. Maybe it's the `with` clause that confuses you. It's there just for the sake of demonstration. You do not need it.

Comment: Ok. I know almost nothing about SQL. So, the "with" clause is not needed. Then, I guess it works fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: @user1777530 What's stopping you? Just add constant value in the select list of the query.

Comment: I use Oracle SQL Developer. I get "cannot insert NULL into (%s)" error when I try the code above. I guess there is something with the insert command. I tried "insert into t2(id, hour) VALUES (select ID, period from t1)", but same error message.

Comment: @user1777530 `cannot insert NULL into` is a pretty much self-explanatory - you are simply trying to insert `NULL` in a column with `NOT NULL` constraint. Besides the `insert` statement you've provided is syntactically incorrect. If you want to insert result set returned by a query there is no need to use `values` clause - it would be simple `insert into t2(id, hour) select ID, period from t1` - but that insert will just copy data without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The test setup:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Period INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Hour INT NOT NULL
    -- There would also be a PK here in real life.
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (3, 2);
```

The actual insert:

```
INSERT INTO t2
WITH CTE (ID, Hour) AS (
    SELECT ID, Period FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Hour - 1 FROM CTE WHERE Hour > 1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```